# Can I install Linux on a SATA drive when UEFI is on SSD in RAID mode?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, raid

I recently got a new PC with an SSD (NVMe) boot drive and a secondary SATA data drive.  After verifying the operation of Windows on the system, I then wanted to try installing Linux on the system.

First of all, the Debian 9 (stable) netinst was unable to recognize either hard drive, so I ended up needing to go to the Debian testing version of netinst.  That was then able to recognize the SATA drive, but still didn't recognize the NVMe drive.  By going to a console and paging through the `dmesg` output, I eventually saw a message to the effect of "BIOS is in RAID mode, switch to AHCI mode".  So, I tried that - after that change, the netinst image was also able to recognize the NVMe device (and confirm that was where the UEFI partition was stored) - but then, Windows would no longer boot.  (Fortunately, switching the BIOS back to RAID mode allowed Windows 10 to boot again.)

So, now I'm wondering where to proceed from here.  Some of the options I can think of would be:

- Switch temporarily to AHCI mode for running the Linux installer, so that it can write `grubx64.efi` to the UEFI partition.  My hope is that then, once GRUB has been loaded from there and hands off control to the kernel image, the kernel can then do everything it needs without access to the NVMe drive.  And `grubx64.efi` doesn't need to be updated very often if at all, anyway.  What I would be nervous about here would be: as far as I understand it, registering `grubx64.efi` with the firmware involves a call to the firmware, so as far as I know, that firmware might then get confused when its partition was originally installed with the drivers in RAID mode, but then it's called with the drivers in AHCI mode, then the firmware is switched back to RAID mode.
- I did find some instructions for switching a Windows 10 installation from RAID mode to AHCI mode in-place ( http://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci ).  However, the article I read just had the bare-bones instructions, and I'm not sure what the implications would be of making this change.  (In my Google search, I did find one forum post indicating that for a single SSD drive it doesn't really make much sense to set up RAID.  Though given that context, I would take that source with a grain of salt.)
- As a last resort, I suppose I could set up GRUB EFI on a USB stick which would then be set up to read the `grub.cfg` etc. from the hard drive.  That would be fairly annoying, though.

My goals here:

- Primarily, I want to be fairly confident that whatever I do will not break the existing Windows 10 installation.  My primary purpose for this system is for gaming, and the Linux installation would be a secondary concern, mostly used for development and testing.  (Therefore, having the root of the Linux installation reside on the SSD would strictly be something I might consider in the future, and is very low priority.  For now, I prefer to reserve the SSD space for whatever games I'm currently playing the most.)
- Secondarily, convenience of booting and upgrading the Linux installation.  (Though here, I tend to build my own system from source, just using Debian as the initial bootstrap system.  In the past I've often ended up installing systemd's EFI booter which relies on kernel and initrd images being installed into the UEFI partition along with some metadata.  If I need to figure out GRUB for the new hardware setup, though, that's certainly an option.)